# Seaborn Stripplot Axis Values with Correct Scaling

Tags: seaborn

I'm trying to plot some data in seaborn where the x values are percentages*100 as floating point numbers (ie 90.909). When I make the plot:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
ax = sns.stripplot(df_12['% ident'], df_12['length'], jitter=True)
```

The decimals in the floating points make the X axis unreadable:

[Initial Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xetp2.png)

I would like to set the x axis to show only whole number multiples of 5 (ie 80, 85, 90, 95, 100).

One method I have tried is the following:

```
fmt = '{:0.0f}'
xticklabels = []
count = 0
for item in ax.get_xticklabels():
    count+= 1
    item.set_text(fmt.format(float(item.get_text())));
    xticklabels += [item];
ax.set_xticklabels(xticklabels);
```

This succeeds in changing the axis values to integers, but the axis looks busy. The numbers shown are also inconsistent between similar datasets.

[Second Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZF2Y.png)

I would like to reduce the total number of values shown on the axis. I have tried to use

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(5))
```

Or similarly

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(5))
ax.set_xticklabels([80, 85, 90, 95, 100])
```

Which give outputs similar to this:

[Third Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PutAj.png)

If you compare this to the previous plot, you'll notice the x axis labels no longer relate to the points plotted. How do I set the values of the x axis while still keeping them related to the points plotted?

Other things I have tried:

```
ax.set_xlim(75, 100)
```

This and any variants result in a blank plot.

```
ax.set(xticklabels=[75,80,85,90,95,100])
```

Does the same thing where the axis labels don't match the data.

```
ax.set(xticks=range(75,101), xticklabels=[75,80,85,90,95,100])
```

Results in all the data points stuck on the left side of the plot with all the axis labels overlapping on a single tick on the right.

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MaxNLocator(integer=True))
```

This doesn't change the axis values to integers, and also appears to cause the axis to no longer correlate with the data.

Comment: `stripplot` is a categorical plot. You are trying to force your categories to obey to numeric laws here, which is really the wrong way of approaching the problem. I guess you rather want to plot a `scatter` plot altogether?